# Flutter's Hot Reload stopped working after updating to Android Studio 4.2.1

Tags: flutter

I just updated to the latest stable Android Studio out there, version `4.2.1`, with all the latest plugin and stuff. After doing it, saving a file didn't update the app. It just showed a bubble saying `reload not performed analysis issues found`, but when going there, only warnings appeared. Zero errors.

Tried a `flutter upgrade` that moved me from `2.0.6` to `2.2.1` with no luck. Also ran an `Invalidate Caches / Restart`, but didn't work either.

Comment: AS version 3.5 is almost two years old (August 2019) - the latest stable is 4.1 imho

Comment: Wow, totally mistyped it! I'm on 4.2.1 :·) Thanks for the message :·)

Comment: i have same issue Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: dev.polek.adbwifi (1.2.4), com.robohorse.robopojogenerator (2.3.5), com.mallowigi (50.2.0), Dart (212.5744), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (212.5457.16), com.github.copilot (1.1.25.1678)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure in Android Studio > File > settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter > check "Perform hot reload on save"!!!

Comment: It was enabled :·(

Answer (score -1):

This may help you:

In Android Studio go to  File -> Settings -> Keymap ->Main menu ->Run, you should assign some key shortcut for that to happen. Default it will be Ctrl+\

Comment: Nope, it should be automatic when saving a file, which is correctly done by default. the issue is something related to the bubble that says `reload not performed analysis issues found`.

Comment: Now try this, go to Run ->debug 'main.dart'. This might help you.

Comment: I just tried it... and nope, it shows the same bubble and doesn't hot reloads the app.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the problem was the fact AndroidStudio placed some `file:///` on some imports when I moved some file locations.

Check if you have any import using `file:///` :

```
import 'file:///<your_awesome_file_path>.dart';
```

and try rewriting them removing the "file:///" argument:

```
import 'package:<your_awesome_package>/<your_awesome_file_name>.dart';
```

The hot reloaded will work again when you replaced all `file:///` occurrences from the imports.

Comment: I'll check it again when it happens! That sadly, happens from time to time... hehehe Thanks @Christian!